# How to (two-level) Meunchian grouping from attribute-based flat XML 

Tags: xml, xslt

I posted a question on this forum last week, and got a really great response, but I realised that I did not go into enough depth, so, after another week of fruitless searching myself, I hope I can find some help here.

[Beginner - XML to XML transformation using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425025/beginner-xml-to-xml-transformation-using-xslt)

I now have an XSL stylesheet which transforms PHP generated XML into a form which is readable as a playlist for a video player. Essentially, this converts a flat structure into one with two layers of hierarchy (user -> sport).

What I forgot to mention before was that I need a third level of hierarchy (user -> sport -> videoID) so that I can hang video attributes off each video.

**Original XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>  
<CONTENT>   
<GALLERY name="John" vid="1" vidtitle="NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - FO sport="Soccer" />       
<GALLERY name="John" vid="2" vidtitle="NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - DL" sport="Golf" />
<GALLERY name="sportshound" vid="28" vidtitle="Tiger Woods" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="sportshound" vid="29" vidtitle="Tigerwoodstest" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="36" vidtitle="5 iron behind April" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="35" vidtitle="face on april" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="34" vidtitle="wqetfgtgdijuserf" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="37" vidtitle="April - 3 iron Behind" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="38" vidtitle="April - 7 iron behind" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="39" vidtitle="April - 3 wood behind" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="40" vidtitle="24 April - 7 iron behind" sport="Golf" />    <GALLERY name="John" vid="41" vidtitle="April 29 Iron behind swing left" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="42" vidtitle="29 April iron behind shallowing" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="43" vidtitle="1st May Driver Behind" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="44" vidtitle="21st May - 6I behind - swing left" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="45" vidtitle="Adam Scott - Masters '11 - iron behind" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="46" vidtitle="19th June 2011 - Face on - impact" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="47" vidtitle="19 June - Behind - 6i" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="48" vidtitle="19 June 2011 - Face on - 8i (impact)" sport="Golf" />    
<GALLERY name="John" vid="49" vidtitle="19 June 2011 - Face On - 5i (impact)" sport="Golf" />    
</CONTENT>
```

**Proposed structure**

```
<CONTENT>   
  <GALLERY name="John">     
   <CATEGORY sport="Soccer">       
     <ITEM>          
      <vid>1</vid>   
      <vidtitle>NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - FO</vidtitle>
     </ITEM>     
   </CATEGORY>     
   <CATEGORY sport="Golf">       
     <ITEM>         
       <vid>2</vid>         
       <vidtitle>NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - DL</vidtitle>
     </ITEM>
     <ITEM>
       <vid>36</vid>   
       <vidtitle>NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - DL</vidtitle>
     </ITEM>
    ............      
   </CATEGORY>   
  <GALLERY/>   
  <GALLERY name="sportshound">     
   <CATEGORY sport="Golf">       
    <ITEM>         
      <vid>28</vid>         
      <vidtitle>Tigerwoodstest</vid>       
    </ITEM>     
     .........
   </CATEGORY>   
  <GALLERY/> 
</CONTENT>
```

**Current XSL Stylesheet**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
version="1.0">    
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    
<xsl:key name="k1" match="GALLERY" use="@name"/>   
<xsl:key name="k2" match="GALLERY" use="concat(@name, '|', @sport)"/>    
<xsl:template match="CONTENT">     
<xsl:copy>       
<xsl:apply-templates select="GALLERY[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @name)[1])]"/>     
</xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="GALLERY">     
<GALLERY name="{@name}">       
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @name)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', concat(@name, '|', @sport))[1])]" mode="sport"/>     
</GALLERY>   
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="GALLERY" mode="sport">     
<CATEGORY sport="{@sport}">       
<ITEM>         
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('k2', concat(@name, '|', @sport))/@vid"/>       </ITEM>     
</CATEGORY>   
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="GALLERY/@vid">     
<vid>       
<xsl:value-of select="."/>     
</vid>   
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your "Proposed output" is not valid XML: `<vidtitle="NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - FO"</vidtitle>`  Please edit your post and correct it.  I suspect you really want `<vidtitle>NL - 22nd Jan 2011 - FO</vidtitle>`

Comment: The answers in the previous question answer this question too.

Comment: +1 to @Jim's comment, although technically he means "not well-formed XML" instead of "not valid XML".

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a third grouping, just wrap the third level items differently.

In your transform you need to replace:

```
<xsl:template match="GALLERY" mode="sport">     
    <CATEGORY sport="{@sport}">       
        <ITEM>         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
              key('k2', concat(@name, '|', @sport))/@vid"/>      
        </ITEM>     
    </CATEGORY>   
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="GALLERY/@vid">     
    <vid>       
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
    </vid>   
</xsl:template>
```

with:

```
    <xsl:template match="GALLERY" mode="sport">     
        <CATEGORY sport="{@sport}">          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
              key('k2', concat(@name, '|', @sport))" 
              mode="item"/> 
        </CATEGORY>   
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="GALLERY" mode="item"> 
        <ITEM>
            <vid>       
                <xsl:value-of select="@vid"/>     
            </vid>
            <vidtitle>
                <xsl:value-of select="@vidtitle"/>
            </vidtitle>
        </ITEM>     
    </xsl:template>
```